# Purely infinite $C^*$-algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

In the book of Rordam, Larsen, Lautsen (exercise 5.7) they give three equivalent definitions for a simple, unital, purely infinite $C^*$-algebra. Assume $A$ is unital, simple and not equal to $\mathbb C$. Then the following are equivalent

- For every non-zero positive $a \in A$ there is some $x \in A$ with $1_A = x^*ax$.
- Every non-zero hereditary sub-$C^*$-algebra of $A$ contains a projection equivalent to $1_A$
- Every non-zero projection in $A$ is properly infinite and every hereditary sub-$C^*$-algebra of $A$ contains a non-zero projection.

I was wondering where the fact is needed that $A$ is simple. For example, I think that the first condition already implies that $A$ is simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is needed for showing $(c) \Rightarrow (a)$ : 
Following the Hint the book suggests you, with the same notations, you find a non-zero, properly infinite projection $p$ in $\overline{aAa}$. A is simple, so $p$ must be a full projection. By 4.9(i) we know that $1_{A} \preceq p$, i.e. there exists a projection $q$ in $A$ s.t. $1 \sim q \leq p$. 
 So, if you take $v\in A$ that implements the equivalence: $v^*v=1_{A}$ and $vv^*=q$ then you get: 
$v^*pv= v^*vv^*pv= v^*qpv=v^*qv=1_{A}$, exactly as the book want you to find.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Do you also see why $w^*aw$ is invertible, if $v^*aw$ is ?

Comment: Yes, let $x\in A$ be s.t. $xv^*aw=1_{A}$, then as $a$ is positive, you can write $xv^*\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a}w=1_{A}$ , that means that $\sqrt{a}w$ is left-invertible. By exericse 5.1 you know that $w^*aw=(\sqrt{a}w)^*\sqrt{a}w$ is invertible.