# Questions about hereditary subalgebra generated by a positive element

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be a unital $C^*$-Algebra ($\mathfrak{A} \neq \mathbb{C}$) and $A$ a positive element with norm smaller or equal to $1$. Knowing that $A \mathfrak{A} A$ is the hereditary subalgebra generated by $A$:

1. (**Answered**) Is there a sufficient (and maybe even necessary) condition (either on $\mathfrak{A}$ or $A$) to tell $A \mathfrak{A} A$ has a projection?
2. (**Open**) Given $c \in [0, 1) \backslash \sigma(A)$, define a function $f$ in $[0, 1]$ such that $f \vert_{[0, c]} =0$ and $f \vert_{[c, 1]}$ is a straight line joining $(c, 0)$ and $(1, 1)$. If $A \mathfrak{A} A$ has a projection, how to show $P \leq E_{A}[c, 1]$? Here $\chi_{[c, 1]}$ is a characteristic function of a component and hence $E_A{[c, 1]} \in \mathfrak{A}$.
3. (**Answered**) Is there a continuous function $g$ defined on $[0, 1]$ such that $g(A) \mathfrak{A} g(A) = A \mathfrak{A} A$?

(**Edit**) For question 1, if the given $\mathfrak{A}$ is simple and purely infinite (for equivalent definitions of **purely infinite** please refer to this [post1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930191)). If $\mathfrak{A}$ is finite-dimensional, then the answer to question 1 will be yes. In general, when $\mathfrak{A}$ is [real rank zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_rank_(C*-algebras)), $A \mathfrak{A} A$ will also have a proper projection (but this might overkill ... Hopefully for a general $\mathfrak{A}$ there will be some restriction on $A$ such that $A \mathfrak{A} A$ will have a proper projection).

(**Edit**) For question 3, in this [post2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2226652) there is a sufficient condition on the function $f$ such that $f(A) \mathfrak{A} f(A) = A \mathfrak{A} A$. The answer in this post proved that whenever $f(0) = 0$ and $f$ strictly positive in $[0, 1]$ then $f(A) \mathfrak{A} f(A) = A \mathfrak{A} A$. The direction here is the same the one mentioned by Prahlad.

Comment: A lazy comment: (1) is true if $\mathfrak{U}$ has real rank zero, but that is perhaps overkill. (3) is true if the support of $g$ coincides with $\sigma(A)$, the spectrum of $A$. See, for instance, Prop 2.5 of https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.3381

Comment: For question 3, if $g$ is the identity function $x\mapsto x$, then $g(A)=A$.  For question 2, given that $\mathfrak A$ is just a $C^*$-algebra, how can you confirm that $E_A[c,1]$ exists (as an element of $\mathfrak A$?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Thank you for your answer. For question 1 that's one of the sufficient conditions. Being real rank zero can imply there is an approximate unit of projections. I hope I can see more conditions and put them together. For question 1, do you mean when $g \vert_{[0, 1]} \geq 0$ and $\sigma(A) \subseteq supp[g]$ then $g(A) \mathfrak{A} g(A) = A \mathfrak{A} A$?

Comment: @Aweygan Thank you for your response I might need to edit the question because I would like to see if I can find out all functions $g$ such that $g(A) \mathfrak{A} g(A) = A \mathfrak{A} A$. The mapping $x \mapsto x$ is one of them but I wonder if there are more. Here $E_A[c, 1]$ is actually $\chi_{[c, 1]}(A)$ and by $L^{\infty}$-Functional Calculus, $\chi_{[c, 1]}(A) \in W^*(A) \subseteq \mathfrak{A}$.

Comment: $C^*$-algebras are not closed under the $L^\infty$-functional calculus.  You would need $\mathfrak A$ to be a von Neumann algebra.  If $c$ is not in the spectrum of $A$, then the indicator function of $[c,1]$ is continuous and $E_A[c,1]$ lies in $\mathfrak A$, but if $c$ is in the spectrum there's no way to make sense out of $E_A[c,1]$, without more structure (such as a representation, or looking at the bidual $\mathfrak A^{**}$).

Comment: @Aweygan That is my mistake. Thank you for pointing it out. Here I wonder, in general, if any existing projection in $B \mathfrak{A} B$ will be affected by the spectrum of $B$ but forget that spectral projection might not be in $\mathfrak{A}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 is not true.  Let $X=\{\frac1n:n\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{0\}$ with the topology inherited from being a subspace of $\mathbb R$, let $\mathfrak A=C(X)$, and let $f\in C(X)$ be the function $f(x)=x$.  Then the projection $E_f[\frac34,1]$ (i.e. the characteristic function of the set $\{1\}$) is a minimal projection, while the hereditary subalgebra $fC(X)f$ contains plenty of projections.

Comment: In your example, $C(X) = \{v \in \ell^{\infty}[\mathbb{N}]\,\vert\,\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} v[k]\,\text{exists}\,\}, f = (1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \cdot)$ and $E_f[\frac{3}{4}, 1] = e_1 = (1, 0, 0, 0, \cdot)$. Under pointwise muplication, projection in $C(X)$ can only has each coordinate either equal to $1$ or $0$. I believe $e_1$ is the only projection in $f C(X) f$ and hence $e_1 = E_f[\frac{3}{4}, 1]$.

Comment: Consider the projection $e_2=(0,1,0,0,\ldots)$.  We have $fe_2f=(0,\frac14,0,0,\ldots)$, so 
$$e_2=f(4e_2)f\in fC(X)f.$$

Comment: Got it. You are right.